# Send a file to a specific path in a server

Tags: python, file, transfer

I am trying to send a file from my PC to many servers to a specific folder in the server directory using one script, for keeping things simple, I am trying in the beginning to send one file to one server instead of many.

I am already connected to a server using a key for authentication, so I do not need to use any login info in my code. I have used the following:

```
import pysftp as sftp

def Filetransfer():
    try:

        s = sftp.Connection(host='IP address')# this is where the server ip address is inserted

        remotepath='/xx/yy/file.txt'# where my file will be transferred to
        localpath='C:/Users/David/Desktop/file.txt'# this is the file location in my PC
        s.put(localpath,remotepath)
        s.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

Filetransfer()
```

I get the following Exception:

```
AttributeError: "'Connection' object has no attribute '_transport_live'" in <bound method Connection.__del__ of <pysftp.Connection object at 0x0000000002E1F3C8>>
```

I have tried to insert the server port beside the IP address, it did not help as I get the same error.

Comment: are you absolutely sure you're using the right password and connecting over an open port?

Comment: hej danidee, I am connected  to a server with Pulse Secure SW. Se this https://www.pulsesecure.net and login is done by entering my username and a key generator. and I can navigate to the servers and connect to each one using SecureFX tool.So what I need is instead of dragging a file from my PC to a specific folder in the servers manually, to do it automatically instead. I don't this it should be a problem with the code I have above but I don't get why I get this error :(

Comment: even though you're logged in to the server from another program. There is no way your python script can know that you're logged in. so you need to use a login information in your script also

Comment: Hi danidee, I understand what you mean, but the problem is when i connect to a server through SecureFX tool I get connected immediately without the need insert my user name and password, because the user name and password (key generator password) is only inserted once  using pulsesecure tool, afterwords no login information required from the server to connect, it is just double click on the server name from the database in SecureFX. The password is key generated and it is not required from the server but from PulseSecure software. I hope that i did not confuse you.And thanks for your help.

Comment: I have got some progress, I was setting a wrong port. now the line above is changed to s = sftp.Connection('IP address','port number') and when I run it I get no error but a message: You have not specified a password or key. so here my problem, I can't set a user name an password in the line above, because as I said that the server does not  require a login info, it is from  SecureFX (requires key generator) once this step done then I can select a server and double click on it to enter to a command line interface without the need to any login. So what login info I should write in the code??

Comment: `sftp.Connection(host="your_host", port="your_port", username="user_name", private_key="private_key")` you can also change key to password

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
sftp.Connection(host="your_host", port="your_port", username="user_name", private_key="private_key")
```

if you're still having problems change `private_key` to `password`

check out the documentation

http://pysftp.readthedocs.org/en/release_0.2.8/pysftp.html

Comment: Hi danidee, I have managed to solve the problem by getting servers  login info from our company website. I did not use port. The problem I have now is that a cluster of servers have different login infofrom the rest. So I need to write a condition if a login failed then try another login info. I do not know how to do it yet, if you can give me a hint it would be great  Thank you very much for the document, I will definitely use it in an other projects.

Comment: Hello, I have managed to  solve the issue of having servers with different login info. I have used 2 different Lists each list has login info (username/password) that corresponds to it, and 2 for loops. I was hoping to do  a smarter code, where I have to make only one List that contains servers that have 2 different login info , by using maybe a while loop. But unfortunately I did not succeed, but for now I am stiaisfed with my current awkward code :) when I have a luxury of time I will try to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: you can use a dictionary and make your script ask the user for the server he wants to connect to e.g `servers = {'server1': ['username1', 'password1'], 'server2': ['username2', 'password2']}` then you can easily do `servers.get('server1', 'Sorry that server doesn't exist')`. if the user specifies server1 that should return the list containing the connection details for server1 or the error message if it was not found....and by the user i mean you :)